# Control how much ExoPlayer time bar shifts when scrubbing with D-PAD

Tags: exoplayer, android-progressbar, android-tv, d-pad

I am trying to customize how much does the time jump when the ExoPlayer's exo_progress Time Bar is focused and the D-PAD left and right buttons are pressed to move back/forward in time through the content. By default it jumps 6 minutes which is a bit much.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the TimeBar's setKeyTimeIncrement property.